weasyprint generates blurry/opaque image
I am using the weasyprint library to export a pdf based on html and css code. However, it generates very inconsistent images. Sometimes the images look like they are opaque. In this code I generate an image of a histogram twice, where the first image looks opaque and the second looks normal. As you can see on the image below. Can anyone tell me why this happens and how I fix it?

HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    {% load static %}
    <link href="{% static 'livedata/css/main.css' %}" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>PDF Preview</title>
</head>
<body>
<div><h1>Summary report {{scout.name}}</h1>
    <h6 style="color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); font-size: 20px;">15-04-2024 11:54:20 - 15-05-2024
        11:54:20</h6>
</div>

<h2 style="color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); margin-bottom: 1em;">Engine speed and load over time</h2>
<img src="{% static 'livedata/plots/'%}plot.jpg" alt="..." width="700" height="400">

<div style="height: 100px;"></div>
<h2 style="color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); margin-bottom: 1em;">Engine speed</h2>

<div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="report-card" style="width: 160px; height: 160px; margin-right: 16px;">
            <p class="report-description">Minimum</p>
            <p class="report-value">1492</p>
            <p class="report-description">RPM</p>
        </div>
        <div class="report-card" style="width: 160px; height: 160px; margin-left: 16px; margin-right: 16px;">
            <p class="report-description">Maximum</p>
            <p class="report-value">1503</p>
            <p class="report-description">RPM</p>
        </div>
        <div class="report-card" style="width: 160px; height: 160px; margin-left: 16px;">
            <p class="report-description">Average</p>
            <p class="report-value">1500</p>
            <p class="report-description">RPM</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <img src="{% static 'livedata/plots/'%}speed_histogram.jpg" alt="..." width="480" height="524">
</div>

<img src="{% static 'livedata/plots/'%}speed_histogram.jpg" alt="..." width="480" height="524">
</body>
</html>

CSS:
.report-card {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 3px solid #EDEFEC;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.report-card > .row,
.report-card .col {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0; /* Override any default Bootstrap margins */
}

.report-card .col {
    flex-direction: column;
}

.report-value,
.report-description {
    width: 100%; /* Ensures text elements fill the flex container */
    text-align: center; /* Center text horizontally */
    margin: 0; /* Remove any default margins that might cause misalignment */
}

.report-value {
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 8px;
    line-height: 0.8;
    padding: 0;
}

.report-description {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    width: 100%; /* Ensures text elements fill the flex container */
    text-align: center; /* Center text horizontally */
    margin: 0; /* Remove any default margins that might cause misalignment */
    white-space: nowrap; /* Prevents the text from wrapping */
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.col-8, .col-4 {
    flex: 0 0 auto; /* Prevent flex items from growing or shrinking */
}

.col-8 {
    width: 66.66%; /* Approximate division of 8/12 of the row */
}

.col-4 {
    width: 33.33%; /* Approximate division of 4/12 of the row */
}

.col-9 {
    width: 75%; /* Approximate division of 9/12 of the row */
}

.col-3 {
    width: 25%; /* Approximate division of 3/12 of the row */
}

#speed-load-chart {
    width: 100%; /* Full width of the report card */
    flex-grow: 1; /* Allow the chart to fill available space */
}

